# load level from image lwjgl

Tags: java, image, load, maps, lwjgl

How can I load levels from an image in LWJGL.  I am making a first-person dungeon crawler much like [this](http://s3.amazonaws.com/ld48/index.html) or like [Delver](http://www.delvergame.com/), I know that Delver has an editor and the levels are exported as images for tiles and then hight. How can I load those render out the map?

Comment: See the various `ImageIO.read(..)` methods.

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to have two images. The correctly textured one, and then the heightmap. ex:

Textured level:
[image: Textured level]

Height level (darker the color, the higher the height):[image: Height level]

You then sift through the pixels of the heightmap and set the heights on the textured. You would have to use the textured one as a spritesheet --> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xj_qZ3Cw08Q
Hope it helps